# prevent move to next cell if this cell is null in devexpress gridview

Tags: gridview, devexpress, cell, spam-prevention, notnull

I have a Grid View in Windows Form application in C# .
editable property is set true at the all columns . When user types any text in cell in Grid View  can move to next cell .
i do not want move to next cell until user type any text .
if no types any text can not move to next cell ,i can not found leaving event for cell or row and i try some options in the design grid view

Comment: It's hard to define "moving to next". Maybe, it would be better if you check all columns before leaving the row and prevent that if there are nulls.

Comment: public event DataGridViewCellEventHandler CellLeave ?

Comment: thanks  Marko Juvančič 
how can do check all column befor leaving the row and prevent that if there are null . i use gridview control for devexpress

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the GridView's [ValidatingEditor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.BaseView.ValidatingEditor.event) event.

See also: [Cell Values, Editors, and Validation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/753/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Data-Editing-and-Validation/Cell-Values-Editors-and-Validation)

Comment: can you put simple example 

or put code c# with event

Comment: There is a code sample in the first link  I provided above.